# Joining tables with where clause dynamically

Tags: sql-server

Table1

| ID | WhereField | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Column1 | 2 |
| 2 | Column2 | 3 |

Table2

| ID | Column1 | Column2 | Somedata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 2 | Some data |
| 2 | 6 | 3 | Some more data |

With the current scenario, I have 2 tables that need to be joined, the second table's field name is defined as value on the first table.

I need to get the data that needs to be joined with a where clause dynamically such as:

```
select * from Table1 T1
inner join T1.WhereField  on T2. "Dynamic where field column"
where T2."Dynamic where field column" = t1.Value
```

Is this even achieveable?

Comment: No, you can't do this. If you have this type of design you have design flaw; you need to go back and rethink your design choices.

Comment: It is achievable through a very convoluted dynamic SQL approach, but at that point the question arises if it's even worth it.  The resulting dyanmic SQL statement created would not look like what you're thinking, rather it would produce a non-dynamic SQL statement that the db engine could actually interpret.  The dynamic parsing that you're suggesting just does not exist in SQL Server.

Comment: You'd be lucky to have this be SARGable all the time as well, which means even if you *could* do it, you definitely SHOULDNT, but I think Larnu already illustrated that but in different words. The normalization rule breaking here has me internally screaming "SO HELP ME CODD." While I may be delving in a little DB Design humor here, it certainly isnt anything you should want to do, even if youre working with a design you have no choice in changing.

Comment: That is a design that was offered to me unfortunately, cheers all, i think i will push for refactoring